# jQuery Email Regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have been developing a script and I'm stumped right now. I have tried many different Regex from Google and non have worked, this is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var email_check = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6}$/;
    num = 0;
    $('#email').focus(function() {
        $('#email_check').show();
        $(this).keyup(function() {
            error = 0;
            var email = $('#email').val();
            num = num+1;
            if(!email_check.test(email)) {
                error = 1;
            }
            if(error == 0) {
                $('#email_check').html('O'+num+email+error);
            }else if(error == 1) {
                $('#email_check').html('X'+num+email+error);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Any help is great, thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set the case insensitive flag (i):

```
var email_check = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6}$/i;
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks, something so simple but so irritating haha!

Comment: does email address can be start with `%`. I think  even `%` is not allowed

Answer (score 2):

You could skip writing the regex and use the [jQuery validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) for this task.  There's an example [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/email) of validating an email address.